# Partition By Multiple Nested Fields in Kafka Connect HDFS Sink

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

We are running kafka hdfs sink connector(version 5.2.1)  and needs HDFS data to be partitioned by multiple nested fields.The data in topics is stored as Avro and has  nested elements.How ever connect cannot recognize the nested fields and throws an error that the field cannot be found.Below is the connector configuration we are using. Doesn't hdfs sink connect support partitioning by nested fields ?.I can partition by using non nested fields

```
{
            "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector",
            "topics.dir": "/projects/test/kafka/logdata/coss",
            "avro.codec": "snappy",
            "flush.size": "200",
            "connect.hdfs.principal": "test@DOMAIN.COM",
            "rotate.interval.ms": "500000",
            "logs.dir": "/projects/test/kafka/tmp/wal/coss4",
            "hdfs.namenode.principal": "hdfs/_HOST@HADOOP.DOMAIN",
            "hadoop.conf.dir": "/etc/hdfs",
            "topics": "test1",
            "connect.hdfs.keytab": "/etc/hdfs-qa/test.keytab",
            "hdfs.url": "hdfs://nameservice1:8020",
            "hdfs.authentication.kerberos": "true",
            "name": "hdfs_connector_v1",
            "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
            "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
            "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://myschema:8081",
            "partition.field.name": "meta.ID,meta.source,meta.HH",
            "partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.FieldPartitioner"
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added nested field support for the TimestampPartitioner, but the FieldPartitioner still has an outstanding PR

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-common/pull/67

Comment: I did see the TimeStampPartitioner and assumed it was done for  FieldPartitioner.This  looks like a very common  use case to me

Comment: Hey @cricket_007, nice PR. Hope gets approved soon.
This fix could be also used in s3-sink.properties "partition.field.name", for avro files, with multiple partition field names? How would it be used in .properties file?
Thank you

Comment: @Julia Yes, it can be used in both HDFS and S3. It should work for any file type, and .properties and JSON files share the same key value pairs. Note: Connect-Distributed mode (JSON configs) is preferred

Comment: Thank you, @cricket_007. Can I use anything similar (in .properties file) or should I use another format:
partition.field.name= 'field1', 'field2'?

I wanted to have my partition like field1 > field2.
Thanks again!

Comment: @JuliaBel That PR only does a single field, not multiple

Comment: Thank you, @cricket_007. I will continue looking for this answer in a topic more related to it.

Comment: @Jul Actually, it might do multiple. Sorry, it's been 2 years since I wrote that code https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-common/blob/master/partitioner/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/storage/partitioner/FieldPartitioner.java#L40

Comment: Don't worry :)
I saw this implementation, that is why my question. Couldn't find an example to implement it in an .properties so far, only for .json.

Comment: @Jul as mentioned, the key values are the same. Replace colon with equals drop quotes on the key. Everything is the same

Comment: So what is the status: can we or not partition by multiple fields using KAFKA Connect? Not clear to me still.

Comment: @thebluephantom You can. Pull the PR and build it

Comment: OK, nice to know. Cheers there in TX.